# Receiving error: connect ECONNREFUSED when using postman to submit POST request to AWS S3 api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, postman

I am receiving the following error when attempting to send a POST request from Postman (form-data) to an API on my server that is supposed to upload a file to my AWS S3 bucket:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 162.255.119.39:443
```

This is the code for the image uploader route

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const upload = require('../services/image-upload.js');

const singleUpload = upload.single('image');



router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  
  singleUpload(req, res, (err) => {
    
    return res.json({'imageUrl': req.file.location});
  });
  
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the code for the API that sends the POST request to AWS:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');


aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: 'secret-access-key',
  accessKeyId: 'access-key-id',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();
 
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'my-bucket',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName:'Testing_meta_data!'});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    }
  })
});

module.exports = upload;
```

At first I thought it was because I had blocked public access to my bucket because after I lifted the restriction, the request went through. But that no longer seems to be the case as I'm still getting an error.

For reference, I am on an actual hosted server, I am not using localhost.

Comment: You are trying to use HTTPS (port 443). Is your application correctly setup to handle HTTPS?

Comment: @Marcin no, my application is set to the default port. How would I change this, if needed?

Comment: It does not work only only in postman, or in any case?

Comment: @Marcin it doesn't work in any case

Comment: @Marcin looks like it's just an issue with postman, i switched to a different api tester and am having no issues. Will use the other one going forward

Comment: Ok. If you don't mind I will provide an answer then.

Comment: please add screen shots from postman

Comment: ANd also how it worked in other api tester software

Comment: you can also give this a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/77072069/12098728.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that postman was trying to use **HTTPS** (port 443) for connections, which is not supported by the application. Connections on port 80 (HTTP) work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

econnrefused means there where no service running in the port ,  https default port is 443. if your system is setup to use anyother port for https then specify that in url

**https://ip:port/resource**

```
https://162.255.119.39:8443/something
```

If you are using hostname then hostname:port

```
https://www.reqres.in:443/api/users?page=1
```

IF your system doesn't use https then remove that from url:

```
http://162.255.119.39:8443/something
```

Here [www.requres.in](http://www.requres.in) is the hostname